# How can I audit deletions that affect me?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, deleted-posts

How can I audit deletions that affect me? i.e.

- My own questions that got deleted.
- My own answers that got deleted by someone else (possible?)
- Questions that got deleted in which I've answered

Comment: I guess I don't really care about users who get deleted whose votes for me are thus nullified, but the above 3 are important, because I think they're still reversible to a certain extent.

Comment: +1... It is not the first time that I am searching for one of my answers, only to discover (through the Google Search Cache) that the whole question had been deleted.

Comment: to the second bullet point; yes, site moderators can delete answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy actually. Browse `/reputation` every day (or every hours), save it to your computer by datetime, and compare with diff tools later on. If you found any line missing, those are deleted.

Comment: Yep, this is what I've been doing recently. I've had many deletions from way before, though, and honestly, some of those deletions aren't warranted. This is related to the recent questions on meta about deletion getting out of hand. I too think this is the case.

Comment: @YOU That's easy?