# How to know the "Number of days I have hit reputation cap on SO"?

Tags: reputation, questions, daily-reputation-limit, support

Is there a way to know the number of days I have hit reputation cap on stackoverflow.com ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and scroll to the very bottom.

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. But that looks like a hidden feature. Why was it not given a prominent link on the profile page?

Comment: Because it is a hidden feature.

Answer (score 4):

You can see this information in the [reputation audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) (see [*How do I audit my reputation?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation) for what all the numbers mean).

As of now there are two days counting numbers, *reached* and *exceeded*. Here's a quote from Jeff Atwood (from [*How is it possible to exceed the rep cap without reaching it?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49402/how-is-it-possible-to-exceed-the-rep-cap-without-reaching-it)):

> ***Jeff Atwood***: did you reach 200 rep from PURE UPVOTES? That's *"reached"*. Did you reach 200 or more rep from upvotes + accepts? That's *"exceeded"*. Neither calculation includes bounties.
>
> [Epic/Legendary badge calculation is...] based on *exceeded*, though the description is mildly incorrect and would lead you to believe it is based on *reached*.

So for example, if you receive 19 upvotes on answers and 1 acceptance, that's 205 points. If this lasts until the end of the day, you have *exceeded*, but not *reached* the reputation cap.

There seems to be some confusion about the exact rule for *exceeded* (as discussed in [*Does acquiring only 200 reps in a day from only votes count toward Epic/Legendary?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56620/does-acquiring-only-200-reps-in-a-day-from-only-votes-count-toward-epic-legendary)). If you only get 200 pts, it may not count toward *exceeded*. To be safe, you should try to score strictly greater than 200 pts.

Do note that you may lose a day that previously counted towards *exceeded/reached* when e.g. you lose an acceptance or the question was deleted.

> [Martin Smith in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61091/why-did-i-get-the-epic-badge/61173#61173): If you exceed the repcap only to have a question deleted on you is it fair to retrospectively say you didn't?

Regardless of fairness, this seems to be the case (though I haven't been able to find a credible source).

With regards to `{Epic}/{Legendary}`, as of very recently there is a discrepancy between the number of *exceeded* days in the reputation audit and the number of days used in the badge-granting algorithm. The discrepancy is caused by deletions (and lost acceptances), which causes some data to be out-of-sync.

Here's an excerpt from [*Shouldn't I have received the Legendary badge by now?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62480/shouldnt-i-have-received-the-legendary-badge-by-now/62601#62601):

> ***Jarrod Dixon***: There's an issue with how the badge is calculated - it uses the `TargetRepChange` field on the votes table to aggregate the total rep gained for a day.
>
> `TargetRepChange` is a denormalized representation of how much an individual vote is worth to receiving user. For example, an up vote on an answer could record 10 in the field. If the receiving user had reached the rep cap for the day, 0 would be recorded.
>
> Things can get messy when a user's posts are deleted - because `TargetRepChange` is set when the vote is cast, a deletion on a future day could cause the rep cap to no longer be reached, even if there were more votes garnered.

So deletion/lost acceptances can sometimes cause inconsistencies between various parts of the system.

There is currently no convenient way to audit deletions that affect you (see: [*How can I audit deletions that affect me?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49967/how-can-i-audit-deletions-that-affect-me)). You are also currently not notified of lost acceptances (see: [*Please show us when we lose an accepted answer*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer)).

Comment: Thanks for such a lengthy and detailed response.